# Question about the tense

Tags: meaning

In a conversation of two people, one says to the other,
*I just got a box of cubans. Maybe I **bring** 'em by your office around 5:00*
In the latter sentence, the present tense, *bring*, is used.
It seems possible to use *I would bring* or *I could bring*.
what kind of meaning is implied when using the present tense?

Comment: It's a mark of substandard colloquial speech (or non-native speaker) to omit the future marker ***will*** (or ***can / could***, depending largely on any intended nuance of requesting permission) in contexts like this. Avoid it, and don't waste any time trying to deconstruct the "grammar".

Comment: (Note that ***will*** would often be contracted to ***'ll*** anyway, and might well be so "understressed" that even though the speaker ***thinks*** he's articulating the word, you as a non-native speaker might simply not ***hear*** it.)

Answer (score 1):

English tenses have a complicated relationship to time. In its simplest form, the present tense indicates action happening right now. There are two problems with the present tense in your example. The first is that you just got a box of cigars at say, 4:00, and you're talking about delivering them at 5:00, which is in the future. The simple present won't do since it indicates action at 4:00. So you could say

> I **will** bring 'em by your office around 5:00.

The second problem is that because you've said "maybe," you're not sure whether the 5:00 delivery is possible or desirable. To get those senses, you'll need to use **auxiliary verbs** to express modal meaning, i.e., meaning not connected to time:

Seeking permission:

> **May** I bring 'em by your office around 5:00?

Asking about propriety:

> **Should** I bring 'em by your office around 5:00?

Asking about possibility:

> **Could** I bring 'em by your office around 5:00?

Don't be fooled by the plain form *bring* which is used in these cases. The plain form of the verb is also used for the present tense, but all the action considered is in the future.

There are two times when the present tense is appropriate for other than the present moment. The first is historical narrative (past time) that is transposed to the **present** tense for immediacy:

> I **remember** my first job, a tough one. I **get** up at 4:00 so I **can** be at the market at 4:30 where I **buy** the cigars. Then I **bring** 'em by the office around 5:00. Afterwards I **have** ten minutes to get a quick breakfast.

Here the narrator remembers (present tense) now about a job in the past but relates all the duties of that job in the present tense as well. The past tense (*got*, *could*, *bought*, *brought*, *had*) are natural here as well.

The so-called **enduring** present tense is also used to indicate habitual or long-standing action that has taken place for a long time, happens now, and is expected to continue.

> **Q:** Tell me about your cigar delivery duties.
>   **A:** I **bring** 'em by your office around 5:00